# Cannot update tweet using twitterizer in c# (error: ssl required)

Tags: c#, asp.net, ssl, oauth, twitterizer

The following code is from  the internet, it shows error at line

TwitterResponse as -- > `{"errors":[{"message":"SSL is required","code":92}]}`

I need some help to know what ssl error so that I can post tweet from the page

```
using System;
using Twitterizer;

public partial class WebForm1 : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var oauth_consumer_key = "47WM3bdfOIpYz9dfbsaPsrXx4";
        var oauth_consumer_secret = "XkxdsbbdfbdsfbbnQyoAxnS8U7q5TOzv";

        if (Request["oauth_token"] == null)
        {
            OAuthTokenResponse reqToken = OAuthUtility.GetRequestToken(
                oauth_consumer_key,
                oauth_consumer_secret,
                Request.Url.AbsoluteUri);

            Response.Redirect(
                string.Format("https://twitter.com/oauth/authorize?oauth_token={0}",
                reqToken.Token));
        }
        else
        {
            string requestToken = Request["oauth_token"].ToString();
            string pin = Request["oauth_verifier"].ToString();

            var tokens = OAuthUtility.GetAccessToken(
                oauth_consumer_key,
                oauth_consumer_secret,
                requestToken,
                pin);

            OAuthTokens accesstoken = new OAuthTokens()
            {
                AccessToken = tokens.Token,
                AccessTokenSecret = tokens.TokenSecret,
                ConsumerKey = oauth_consumer_key,
                ConsumerSecret = oauth_consumer_secret
            };

            TwitterResponse<TwitterStatus> response = TwitterStatus.Update(
                accesstoken,"Testing!! It works (hopefully)."); //-->{"errors[{"message":"SSL is required","code":92}]}

            if (response.Result == RequestResult.Success)
            {
                Response.Write("we did it!");
            }
            else
            {
                Response.Write("it's all bad.");
            }
        }
    }    
}
```

}

Comment: Maybe hide key and secret?

Answer (score 0):

i got the result By replacing TwitterResponse< TwitterStatus> line with following code.

```
 TwitterResponse<TwitterStatus> response = TwitterStatus.Update(
                accesstoken, 
                "Testing!! It works (hopefully)2.",
                new StatusUpdateOptions() { UseSSL = true, APIBaseAddress = "http://api.twitter.com/1.1/" });
```